# Object.keys() Get Number Of Child Items

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have the following data source -- converted to JSON using to XML using X2JS:

```
{
    "blog": {
        "article": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "author": "eat-sleep-code",
                "title": {
                    "__cdata": "Thefirstarticle."
                },
                "content": {
                    "__cdata": "\nThisismyfirstarticleinmytestsite.\n"
                },
                "createdate": "2014-05-09"
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "author": "eat-sleep-code",
                "title": {
                    "__cdata": "Thesecondarticle."
                },
                "content": {
                    "__cdata": "\nThisismysecondarticleinmytestsite.Thisarticle'screatedateisactuallyearlier.\n"
                },
                "createdate": "2014-05-08"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I am trying to find the number of "articles".

`Object.keys(jsonObject).length;` just gets me 1.   I am guessing because it is finding one "blog" item.

Comment: Well if you want the number of `articles`, don't you think you would need to reference the `articles` property?

Comment: if it is a string, JSON.parse(jsonObject).blog.article.length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jsonObject.blog.article.length
```